# Audio Route Button - AirPlay

Tags: ios, audio, airplay, audioqueue

I am currently playing audio through AudioQueues.  I would like to allow users to connect to Airplay devices.

If I create an MPVolumeView and use the 'showsRouteButton' to display the route button I can successfully connect.

Is there a way to change the Audio Route to Airplay without using the MPVolumeView?  Or a simpler Apple view that is just the route button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any other way to show the airplay route button (at least in current SDK iOS 5.1).. If you want to show AirPlay options you have to use MPVolumeView..

Comment: I found I can customize the MPVolumeView, so this will work  
 mAirPlayBtn.showsVolumeSlider = false;

Answer (score 2):

1 hide MPVolumeView and make it as global var

```
CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.origin.x = 410; // out of the screen
_volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[_volumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:NO];
[_volumeView setShowsRouteButton:YES];
[self.view addSubview:_volumeView];
```

2 simulate button tapes

```
- (IBAction)handleAirPlay:(id)sender {
        for (UIButton *button in _volumeView.subviews)
        {
            if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                [button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 11 you can use AVRoutePicker :

```
import AVKit 

let rpv = AVRoutePickerView()
view.addSubview(rpv)
```